# SimpleXML change Excel

Tags: php

i want to change the attribute `ss:ExpandedColumnCount` with php simpleXML.

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="5" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1322" x:FullColumns="1"           x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="60">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="112.5"/>
   <Column ss:Index="3" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="615"/>
   <Column ss:Index="5" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="459"/>
</Table>
```

i need to change `ss:ExpandedColumnCount` to 6.

```
$file = simplexml_load_file($datei);
```

how can i get access to the data?

Solution:

```
$file->Worksheet->Table[0]->attributes('ss', TRUE)->ExpandedColumnCount = $max_size +1;
```

Comment: yes but i found the solution!

Comment: Awesome! You should post it as an answer to the question, rather than as part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$file->Worksheet->Table[0]->attributes('ss', TRUE)->ExpandedColumnCount = $max_size +1;
```